# SceneForm is Deprecated, how to create an AR app in 2023? - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to create a simple AR app for Android. My aim is to make an app that can recognize the environment using only Kotlin and obtain the user's location. However, I have been facing difficulty in finding tutorials or documentation that do not rely on deprecated libraries such as SceneForm.

If anyone has any tips or resources on how I can create an AR app using only kotlin, I would appreciate any help or advice you can offer. Thank you in advance.

I have come across a guide from the ARCore documentation, which places objects in the view, but this is not what I need. Additionally, I would prefer a step-by-step guide that explains the code as I am new to AR. https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart

If there is anything else I should know about AR development, specifically for Android, please let me know, and if possible, direct me to the right sources.

Comment: maybe this would be helpful https://github.com/SceneView

Comment: Thanks bro this was helpful. But is there any library maintained by Google itself for AR development?

Comment: When I researched a year ago, I didn't find such a library